Build Custom Search With JIRA JQL
Our company migrated from JIRA on premises to JIRA cloud so I no longer have access to the backend database.
I'm trying to capture all activity that is performed by one of my reports for a given day. For example, I want any ticket my report touched, whether it was a created ticket, updated ticket, or commented on ticket.
Can anyone assist in how I can pull this information?
I'd like to have the report contain the ticket number and link to the ticket, if possible.
I have tried following but get no results returned:
worklogAuthor = <user> and worklogDate = "2024/11/05"

It has come to my attention that worklogAuthor only applies if the user documents an amount of time, so I guess I need something slightly different.

I'm not completely sure i understand what you mean with report. I assume you meant reporter based on the sample jql you provided. In that case you can use the updatedBy() function.
updatedBy(<user>, <date>)

docs
